# Why a code continues when the function doesnt return value yet. (in xmlhttprequest, calling php file.) Is it related to Sync/Async functions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, asynchronous

Came here again with lame questions as I am in process of learning/coding.

I would like to change a property of a disable value on button: During function performing its job, button should be disabled, once function finishes and return the values, button should be enabled again.

In function which creates a buttons I am calling update() function which loading php file via XMLHttpRequest. Then running the php code and return values on page. I want to have button disabled during this time. But everytime I call the function the button will not change. Or if changed it was so fast that I didnt even saw it.

here is a code:

```
    global_button = document.createElement("button");
//    let btn1 = document.createElement("button");
    global_button.innerHTML = "UPDATE";
    global_button.id = "update";
    global_button.disabled = false;
    document.body.appendChild(global_button);
    document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].append(global_button);
    global_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("After CLICKED");
        global_button.disabled = true;
        update();
        global_button.disabled = false;
        console.log("AFTER FUNCTION RETURN VALUES");
```

update function:

```
var xmlhttp;

function loadFile(file, func){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = func;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function update(){
    loadFile("update.php", function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    });
}
```

When I checked the console, it shows both console logs immediately: "After CLICKED" and "AFTER FUNCTION RETURN VALUES" messages. And couples seconds later, result of the function appear. But button wont change whatsoever.

I am suspecting the sync/async functions ? I read something for the .open method and vale true/false, but nothing changed if I switched from true to false. Also thinking if I should put it on the loop or something which will check the button clicked ? But I thought that listener would do the job.

Can anybody check and give me an advice ? or correct my thinking if it's wrong?

many thanks all of you. :)

Comment: `loadFile` doesn't block the code flow. You could move `global_button.disabled = false;` into the callback function of `loadFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed due to the asynchronous nature of the `send` method of `XMLHttpRequest` - and therefore of your `update`, which calls it.

When you call `update()`, which itself calls this:

```
loadFile("update.php", function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
});
```

all that happens is that you set up an `XMLHttpRequest` object and use its `send` method to send a request, telling it to call this function:

```
function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
});
```

as a "callback" when the `readyState` changes. (And in particular, when the request is complete and a response received.) But calling `update` does not wait for that state change to happen and block your code from running - hence the next lines of code, which set the `disabled` state of the button to false and log to the console - are executed straight away. So the button gets disabled but then instantly un-disabled, and therefore you never see it disabled. (In fact the browser will never even "paint" the screen with a disabled button, since it doesn't get a chance to do this while your code is running, so even if you could in theory do a freeze-frame here you would never see a disabled button.)

To fix it, you have to work with the asynchronous code you're using. Anything you want to happen after the state change has to take place in the callback function you pass it. So you can simply fix your problem by changing the `update` definition to this:

```
function update(){
    loadFile("update.php", function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            global_button.disabled = false;
            console.log("AFTER FUNCTION RETURN VALUES");   
        }
    });
}
```

and delete those two lines of code from the place you've currently got them, after the `update` call.

Although note that this will only work if `global_button` is in scope inside `update`, which it might not be depending on how your code is structured (it probably *shouldn't* be to be honest). And even if it does, it's not good to hardcode your `update` to always undisable the button afterwards, with no guarantee the button will even be disabled first.

It's therefore better to define `update` to itself take a callback function:

```
function update(callback){
    loadFile("update.php", function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            callback();   
        }
    });
}
```

and then call it like this in your main code:

```
    global_button.disabled = true;
    update(function() {
        global_button.disabled = false;
        console.log("AFTER FUNCTION RETURN VALUES");
    });
```

because this separates the concerns of `update` itself ("make this request and set the `content` inner HTML to the response"), from whatever you might want to do afterwards, which could be different each time.

Finally, I can't not mention that this callback-based asynchronous code is very old-fashioned now. `XMLHTTPRequest` itself is quite a cumbersome API. I highly recommend you look into its modern equivalent, `fetch`, which is based on Promises - which while not without their mental gotchas are a much more understandable way to write asynchronous code. In particular with `async` and `await` you can write code that looks much like what you originally had: putting `await update();` would actually do what you are waiting, and have the rest of your code wait for `update` to complete. But you can't just make that change to your original code because that only works if `update` returns a Promise, which in turns would mean completely rewriting your `loadFile` to use a more modern, Promise-based approach.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. 

Your answer solved hours of my headache and also showed me how much I dont know, yet :D. But as I am still beginner, I am still learning. I know, the style I have in my code is probably ancient but I am trying to be interested, so to better see results from time to time then just read theory. But I definitely need t o have a look on new and modern variations.

Thanks again. (I am afraid that we might meet again. :))